# Opening a remote Excel file via WebDAV without full WebDAV support

Tags: asp.net, excel, ms-office, webdav

I am looking to implement a fairly simple system where a user can open and edit an Excel file via a link to a WebDAV resource. I am using a custom ASP.NET solution for this (running on Azure, so extra software installation/configuration is very difficult). Doing a basic implementation, I can get the document open, but in read only mode. I have seen a number of posts of how to open in read-write mode, but I am not sure what WebDAV verbs/options that I need to support in order to make this happen on the backend.

Is there a list of verbs that Excel (and Office in general) use when working with a WebDAV resource/file?

Thanks,
Erick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this and writing some prototype code, it appears that you need pretty much all the WebDAV features, including both levels. Or so close to all of them that it isn't worth doing a partial implementation.

Erick

Answer (score 0):

You will need to support the following WebDAV verbs:

COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, UNLOCK

You may omit some of them from OPTIONS response, such as COPY, MOVE or PROPPATCH but from my experience this may lead to MS Office to open documents as read-only.